# Exception thrown at 0x71002A85 (SDL2_ttf.dll)

Tags: c++, sdl-2

So i'm creating a 2D Pong game using SDL2 and C++ (I'm completely new to this!) Everything was going well until I hit this error:

```
Exception thrown at 0x71002A85 (SDL2_ttf.dll) in 2D Game.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
```

the code breaks at:

SDL_Surface* surf = TTF_RenderText_Blended(font, message.c_str(), color);

```
#include "utilities.h"

#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_ttf.h>

void renderTexture(SDL_Texture* tex,
        SDL_Renderer* ren, SDL_Rect dst, SDL_Rect *clip) {
    SDL_RenderCopy(ren, tex, clip, &dst);
}

void renderTexture(SDL_Texture* tex,
        SDL_Renderer* ren, int x, int y, SDL_Rect* clip) {
    SDL_Rect dst;
    dst.x = x;
    dst.y = y;
    if (clip != nullptr) {
        dst.w = clip->w;
        dst.h = clip->h;
    } else {
        SDL_QueryTexture(tex, nullptr, nullptr, &dst.w, &dst.h);
    }

    renderTexture(tex, ren, dst, clip);
}

SDL_Texture* renderText(const std::string &message,
    const std::string &fontFile, SDL_Color color,
    int fontSize, SDL_Renderer* renderer) {

    TTF_Font* font = TTF_OpenFont(fontFile.c_str(), fontSize);

SDL_Surface* surf = TTF_RenderText_Blended(font, message.c_str(), color);

SDL_Texture* texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surf);

SDL_FreeSurface(surf);
TTF_CloseFont(font);

return texture;

}
```

Comment: You didn't test the return from `TTF_OpenFont` for error. `font` may be NULL.

Comment: What's the value of `fontFile` when you execute the code ?

Comment: The value is "FFFFORWA.TTF" i've also just noticed the 'font' value is NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the `font` object returned on the line before for null. It is quite possible that `TTF_OpenFont` returns null if it fails to open the given font file.

```
TTF_Font* font = TTF_OpenFont(fontFile.c_str(), fontSize);

if(!font) {
   ... //some action here, perhaps throw exception
}
SDL_Surface* surf = TTF_RenderText_Blended(font, message.c_str(), color);
```

Comment: Agree, this probably is the cause. Definitely start here, but we can't be certain this is the answer because OP provided too little code to provide a definitive answer. `font` could be just fine and something off-screen has been poorly configured.